# URL Query String, getting multiple values

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string

I'm adapting a WordPress plugin for use on a recruitment agency website.

http://mjtweaverdev.com/jobs/?job_industry=null&job_salary=10000

However, the client needs a select option that goes inbetween two values, for instance 10000-19000. I've tried multiple things but cant get it working.

I've tried `&job_salary=10000, 11000, 12000` .... that didnt work
also `&job_salary=10000&job_salary=11000&job_salary=12000` - that just selected the last option

Is there any way of querying two values so 10000-19000 in the query?

UPDATE: I'm trying the first recommended method, below is the code from the plugin I've tried to tweak, it still isnt working though :/
http://jsfiddle.net/mjtweaver/9ga6u/

Comment: whts unclear in this ??? can u get multiple values from single variable?? by asssgning diff vlues??

Comment: Since you want a range (between some salary range), add `FROM` and `TO` salary in URL and use them in your query (using `BETWEEN` clause).

Comment: @AshishRatan im sorry i dont follow you at all.

Comment: @MichaelWeaver JSFiddle don't execute PHP scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can use `[]` to treat them as array:

```
job_salary[]=10000&job_salary[]=11000&job_salary[]=12000
```

Doing var_dump:

```
var_dump($_GET['job_salary']);
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '10000' (length=5)
  1 => string '11000' (length=5)
  2 => string '12000' (length=5)
```

Comment: But he wants between viz. 10000-19000. Then why not use to-from only and use `BETWEEN` in query.

Comment: @ParagTyagi I'm just giving an alternative way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
http://mjtweaverdev.com/jobs/?job_industry=null&job_salary_from=10000&job_salary_to=19000
```

Your PHP script -

```
<?php

$job_salary_from = $_GET['job_salary_from'];
$job_salary_to = $_GET['job_salary_to'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 
       salary BETWEEN $job_salary_from AND $job_salary_to";
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this, im editing the plugin now, this is what I have but it still isnt working :/
http://jsfiddle.net/mjtweaver/9ga6u/